# Shorter slash (/) for small caps with Baskervaldx?

Tags: fonts, typography, small-caps

I have acronyms with slash in them, like ISO/IEC and I'd like to write them in small caps. The problem is that the slash is quite a bit taller than the letters.

1. OT: Is this really a typographic problem or not? Should I just live with a bit tall slash?
2. Main question: is there a proper/easy way to have a "small cap slash" in the middle? If there is a good font that achieves this, please recommend one.

I'm using now [baskervaldx](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/baskervaldx) package for the font. And this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\begin{document}
\textsc{iso/iec} with a bit too tall slash.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I vertically downsize the text slash to the height of a `\textsc{e}` in the current font size. (note: since `scalerel` processes arguments in math mode by default, using a `$/$` actually processes the slash in text mode).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scslash{\stretchrel*{$/$}{\textsc{e}}}
\begin{document}
\textsc{iso/iec} with a bit too tall slash.

\textsc{iso\scslash iec} with a downsized slash.

\LARGE
\textsc{iso/iec} with a bit too tall slash.

\textsc{iso\scslash iec} with a downsized slash.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The above implementation preserves the glyph width and shrinks the vertical height.  If one wanted the same slant and a narrower glyph, changing the `\stretchrel` to a `\scalerel` would accomplish that:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! The `\scalerel` version produces very good results! Not sure which one on these is typographically the "correct" one but this looks anyway a lot better than the default slash.

Comment: @Paapaa Keeping the same slant (`\scalerel`) is probably more preferred *except* that it also thins out the glyph's rule thickness, which is not preferable.  But unless one redesigns such a glyph into the font set, your options are along either of these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command for the slash:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\textslash}{/}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textslashsc}{%
  \check@mathfonts
  {\fontsize{\sf@size}{\z@}\selectfont/}%
}
\xapptocmd{\scshape}{\let\textslash\textslashsc}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textsc{iso\textslash iec} with a bit too tall slash
and a normal\textslash big slash.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is also a possible approach and the result looks good. Can you explain what happens on the two rows starting with `\check@`?

Comment: @Paapaa The `\check@mathfonts` macro makes some computations to set up sizes for math fonts according to the current font size; in particular it defines `\sf@size` that's the size for subscripts, so we can use this size for the slash, because we add to `\scshape` that `\textslash` should become the “small version”.